# Calling strace within a C program (+Seg fault)

Tags: c, exec, strace, execvp

Instead of calling strace directly from the command line,

**I want to write a program that runs strace for me to a given program.**
I tried to solve this for hours but I just don't know how to get it working.

I previously wrote a program that uses the same piece of code used below.
Previous program simply duplicates the action of shell, and it records user input to a log file. Link: https://pastebin.com/Wf9TTZSM

All I did was take out the relevant codes, and change the user input to run "strace". But it doesn't work.

How can I get this working?

I'm getting the **Seg fault (core dumped)** error for below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{

    char *s = "strace ls";

    char* separator = " ";
    char* argv[64];
    int argc = 0;
    char* tmp;

    printf("%s", s);

    argv[argc] = strtok_r(s, separator, &tmp);
    while( argv[argc] != NULL){
        argc+=1;
        argv[argc] = strtok_r(NULL, separator, &tmp);
    }

    execvp(argv[0],argv);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `char *s = "strace ls";` to `char s[] = "strace ls";`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much I figure it out right after! But my question is, do you have any idea why my code worked fine with char *user_input in my previous program that I linked? Is it because I'm passing it as an argument to the function "execute"?

Comment: Your previous code doesn't show how `execute()` is called. If the argument is a literal string it should fail in the same way, because you're not allowed to modify literals, and that's how `strtok()` works. If you call it with an array containing user input then it can be modified by `strtok()`.

Comment: @Barmar Got it. My execute() is at line 72 btw. If you answer this I will accept you as the answer.

Comment: Duplicate questions can't be answered.

Comment: The previous code has `char user_input[1024];` That's a modifiable array, so no error.